# Can you deploy "Tab Hidden" to a Custom Object on a Profile using metadata API? (tabVisibilities)

Tags: metadata-api, tab, custom-profile, destructivechanges.xml

I have a custom object called **MyCustomObject.object** and a custom profile called **MyCustomProfile.profile**

Currently the tab visibility of **MyCustomObject** is set to **"Default On"** for **MyCustomProfile**.

```
<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>MyCustomObject</tab>
    <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>
```

If I set the tab visibility to "Tab Hidden" through the Salesforce UI, the lines above are removed in MyCustomProfile.profile and when I try and deploy this change through the metadata API the change is not reflected (i.e. the tab visibility remains as "Default On")

I was wondering whether you can access tabVisibilities in destructiveChanges.xml and deploy the tab visibility as a destructive change?

I imagine it might look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>MyCustomProfile.MyCustomObject</members>
    <name>ProfileTabVisibility</name>       
</types>
<version>33.0</version>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are not deleting anything, hence it's not part of the destructiveChanges. If you want to hide a tab, you should make a regular deployment by specifying "Hidden" instead of "DefaultOn" or "DefaultOff".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You need to add **tabVisibilities** metadata to your profile metadata file.
For example, you want to add a Custom tab's visibility to DefaultOn, then the metadata will look like this(Copy paste it in your profile metadata file):

```
<tabVisibilities>
        <tab>CustomTabName</tab>
        <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>
```

Answer (score 0):

Came here looking for solution to a similar problem.

From version 37.0, [ProfileTabVisibility](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) will return `Hidden`, `DefaultOn` or `DefaultOff` irrespective of whether the tab visibility was set via API or via UI. For earlier versions, that seemed to be a problem. However, I'm unable to get the metadata when I retrieve